# MySQL - recreate default mysql database

Tags: mysql

For whatever reason, the "mysql" database on my windows mysql installation has been deleted. I now have a mysql install that cannot start because the system database is missing, but I cannot find any documentation on recreating this database.

How do I recreate the mysql database (with users) on Windows?

Comment: Hehe..."whatever reason". Good way to cover your tracks there, wouldn't want to admit you accidentally the whole database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall MySQL.

Here's an sql dump from my mysql table: http://www.box.net/shared/js92gum4gh.

Answer (score 10):

On Unix, you would move your existing database data directory out of the way and run mysql_install_db. Unfortunately, according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-post-installation.html), you don't have this command on Windows. It claims it is unnecessary because Windows distributions include preinitialized mysql and test databases. This would seem to suggest that you do need to reinstall MySQL.

Comment: If you are on Windows 7 don't forget to delete the folder C:\ProgramData\MySQL after deinstallation - usually it contains the database. If you don't delete it, the database will not be recreated upon installation! Instead you will end up with the old database.

Comment: I have this command on my rather customized version of CentOS and mysql and it says `Installing MySQL system tables...
OK
Filling help tables...
OK
` but doesn't really recreate dropped `mysql` database (also your link is broken, [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html) is ok)

Answer (score 1):

I dropped my `mysql` deafult system database accidentally.

Reinstallation (as accepted answer suggest) is not always possible, so I tried [mysql_install_db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html) first from second answer.

Now it's a part of *mysqld* and you can try `mysqld --initialize` but not on my version of OS and mysql.

Anyway it didn't help me too. So I've read docs carefully and found

> If the data directory does already exist, you are performing an upgrade operation (not an install operation) and should run mysql_upgrade, not mysql_install_db

That did the trick. With [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html) I've restored all system tables.

**ps** I have to mention, that it was fresh install of mysql server, so I didn't care about other databases, settings or users. **Be carefull!!!** You can lose important data.